# Calculation of a specific integral involving the Levy distribution

Tags: reference-request, definite-integrals, closed-form

It is well-known that for a standard Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ the first hitting time of the level $1$
$$T_1 := \inf\{t> 0 : B_t = 1 \}$$
has standard Levy distribution, this means that $T_1$ has the density
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi t^3}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2t}\right)$$

It is also known that $\Bbb E[T_1^n] = \infty $. But is there a closed form expression for
$$\Bbb E[(t-T_1)^n 1_{\{T_1 \leq t\}}] = \int_0^t (t-u)^{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi u^3}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2u}\right) du$$
available?

Context: Im interested in the Laplace transform of the occupation time $\Gamma_t :=  \int_0^t 1_{(-\infty , 1]}(B_s) ds$ for $\lambda \leq 0$.

The distribution of the occupation time $\int_0^t 1_{(-\infty , 0]}(B_s) ds$ has the arcsin distribution by the Levys arcsin law. The laplace transform of the standard arcsin distribution is the function $_1F_1(1/2,1, \lambda).$ Thus we have by $\Gamma_t = T_1 \wedge t + \int_{T_1 \wedge t}^t 1_{(-\infty , 1]}(B_s) ds$ and the Markov property that the Laplace transform of $\Gamma_t $ is given by
$$e^{\lambda t}\Bbb P (T_1 > t) + \int_{0}^t e^{\lambda u} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi u^3}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2u}\right)  {}_1F_1(1/2,1, \lambda (t-u)) du$$

Note that $_1F_1(1/2,1, z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1/2)^{(n)} z^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Could you please share the context/application of this question? Just interested.

Answer (score 2):

For $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $t>0$, *Mathematica* gives:

$$t^n \left(\, _1F_1\left(-n;\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{2 t}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{2} \Gamma (n+1)
   \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-n;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{2 t}\right)}{\sqrt{t} \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)$$

where $F$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind.

For $n = 2$, here is your function of $t$:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: For what it's worth, the term "the hypergeometric function" is usually reserved for $_2F_1$, whereas $_1F_1$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the 1st-kind.